# How to set the test database when using pow and capybara-webkit?

Tags: cucumber, capybara, rack-pow

Integration testing with subdomains works seamlessly using pow and capybara-webkit, except for one small hitch.  This config in my env.rb hits my dev database instead the test db:

```
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
  Capybara.run_server = false
  Capybara.app_host = "http://myDomain.dev"
```

My database.yml is plain vanilla:

```
login: &login
  adapter: mysql
  username: root
  password: 
  #host: mysql.example.com

development:
  <<: *login
  database: site_dev

test: &test
  <<: *login
  database: site_test

production:
  <<: *login
  database: site_prod

cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

So why does this hit the dev db instead of the test db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why shouldn't it? pow is running as a separate process and knows bother about you spec_helper/test_helper, where you set your RAILS_ENV to test. If you want pow to run in test environment you have to explicitly set it, for example `echo export RAILS_ENV=production > .powenv`